# Nginx rewrite location to match proxy rule

Tags: nginx, websocket, sockjs

I want to rewrite a request comming from the

referer `xxx.de/mypath` to the location `xxx.de/sockjs-node?abc` to rewrite to `xxx.de/mypath/sockjs-node?abc`

Currently I have

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
server_name ~^(www)?\.xxx\..*;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

proxy_read_timeout  90;

proxy_redirect off;

location /sockjs-node {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ "${http_referer}$1" break;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}

location /mypath/ {
    rewrite ^/mypath/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://docker.local:3001;
}
```

Can I configure nginx to redirect (all protocols) or rewrite + proxy_pass my requests?

Comment: Maybe with something like mentioned in: https://www.maxcdn.com/one/tutorial/how-to-manipulate-headers-based-on-http-referrer/ ?

Comment: I realized that this question rather belongs to `serverfault` and therefore raised the question there as well: https://serverfault.com/questions/886117/nginx-rewrite-location-to-match-proxy-rule